# Naming Sheets After Given Range

Tags: vba, excel

i have this bit of code and im abit stuck on a solution and was wondering if you could help me:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim wsn As Range
Set wsn = Worksheets("Formula Sheet").Range("C1:C26")
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Do Until ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary Sheet"
ActiveSheet.UnprotectPassword:="admin"
ActiveSheet.Name = (wsn + x)
x = x + 1
With Worksheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
.Protect Password:="admin", userinterfaceonly:=True
.EnableOutlining = True
.EnableAutoFilter = True
End With
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Loop
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

What im trying to achieve is a method of naming all my sheet after sheet 1 but before summary to the range of values listed on my formula sheet (C1:C26 on formula sheet), i have put x in as a variable but i want it to name sheet two C1 sheet 3 C2 and so on, how do i implement the select next function of a range of values (C1:C26) and if this values are selected do not use again.

Hope this is clear :)

Comment: Does your workbook start with 30 sheets named from the left "Formula Sheet"; "General Top Sheet"; "Sheet1"; ..26 other sheets; "Summary Sheet" in column AD?

Comment: Sorry forgot to edit the general top sheet its now called sheet 1

Comment: But are you starting with all 29 sheets or you want to rename sheets after "Sheet1" to whatever is in `C1:C26` on the `Formula Sheet` sheet **OR** you reach the `Summary Sheet` sheet. Just so I'm clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = 1    
Do Until ActiveSheet.Name = "Summary Sheet"
ActiveSheet.UnprotectPassword:="admin"
ActiveSheet.Name = wsn.Cells(x, 1)
x = x + 1

'etc.
```

*Edit in reaction to comment below:*

Try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim wsn As Range
Set wsn = Worksheets("Formula Sheet").Range("C1:C26")
set ws = Worksheets(Worksheets("Sheet1").Index + 1)
Do Until ws.Name = "Summary Sheet"
ws.UnprotectPassword:="admin"
ws.Name = wsn.Cells(x, 1)
x = x + 1
With ws
.Protect Password:="admin", userinterfaceonly:=True
.EnableOutlining = True
.EnableAutoFilter = True
End With
set ws = Worksheets(ws.Index + 1)
Loop
Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This does what i want it to do but now it gives me an error on the line (ActiveSheet.Next.Select) how do i overcome this?

Comment: @Nindi, check the addition to my answer. Is it the first or the second occurence of that line that throws the error?

Comment: This code makes produces more errors in the code. Is there away to ignore error messages because it does exactly what i want but brings and error when it reaches the summary sheet

Comment: Ok. Not the most elegant way, but you can add *On Error Resume Next* before the line that throws the error.

Comment: I really dont want to but i have no clue why i get this error

Comment: Great i implement the ignore error and it freezes my workbook. Dont know what the best solution is

Comment: No it would still give me the error on the ActiveSheet.Next.Select, i think this is because it comes to the summary sheet and doesnt know what to do

Comment: In order to help you any further, I would need to see the file.

Comment: Removal of that line seems to fix it. Thanks for the help :)